# How to add value to join table with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables: `User`, `Department` and `Users_Departments`. Besides joining users and departments on id, which I have working well, I need to set one of the users as the head of the department by setting a boolean on Users_Departments.

I've configured relationships on both users and departments:

```
departments = db.relationship('Department', secondary=users_departments, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

users = db.relationship('User', secondary=users_departments, backref=db.backref('departments', lazy='dynamic'))
```

But I don't know how to set the boolean value that is defined in Users_Departments when I add a user to a department and vice-versa.

Comment: Note: when you define a relationship with `backref` instead of `back_populates`, you only need to define it on one side of the relationship. See the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#linking-relationships-with-backref).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [assocation object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object):

> "The association object pattern is a variant on many-to-many: it’s
>   used when your association table contains additional columns beyond
>   those which are foreign keys to the left and right tables."

In this case you might define the `users_departments` table as an ORM object:

```
class UserDepartment(db.Model): # Since we're using Flask-SQLAlchemy
    __tablename__ = 'users_departments'

    user_id        = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    department_id  = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('departments.id'), primary_key=True)

    is_manager     = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    user       = relationship('User', back_populates='department_assoc')
    department = relationship('Department', back_populates='user_assoc')
```

I have had success using a table like this as `secondary`, with the `viewonly` flag set `True`. So you might define the relationship in the `Users` class:

```
departments = db.relationship('Department',
    secondary='users_departments',
    viewonly=True,
    backref=db.backref('users', viewonly=True, lazy='dynamic'),
    lazy='dynamic')
```

This defines a read-only relationship, where actual changes are made directly on the `users_departments` table:

```
>>> x = UserDepartment(user_id=n, department_id=m, is_manager=False)
>>> db.session.add(x)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Look at the documentation linked at the beginning of this post to understand why `viewonly` is a good idea. The documentation for `viewonly` itself is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.viewonly).

You could also define a column `users.department_assoc` in the `User` class:

```
department_assoc = db.relationship('UserDepartment', back_populates='user')
```

and make changes:

```
>>>> some_user = User.query.get(n)
>>>> some_user.department_assoc.append(UserDepartment(department_id=m,  is_manager=False))
>>>> db.session.commit()
```